# Windows has begun treating the discovery of newer versions of runtimes as an error

Tags: runtime-error, windows-installer

Our deployments are driven by a set of CMDs, wherein we trap the common return codes from installers, e.g. for Windows Installer (MSI) we have 3010, 1641 and 1638.

For the common runtimes, we use a different, single trap, i.e. for a non-zero value. If we encounter such, we branch to an error handler, skipping the remainder of the installation.

Recently, however, Windows has begun treating the discovery of newer versions of these runtimes as an error, returning a negative decimal number, meaning that we're now getting packages which have executed without fail for years resulting in lots of service desk tickets, since the installation gets flagged as 'Failed'.  We now have to trawl through 1,000+ applications looking for runtimes being installed and adding traps for this new value or, depending on which runtime it is, simply removing the error-trapping.

Has anyone else seen this?